# Laravel 5.1: Register user and send data to two tables at the same time: Users and Users_details

Tags: php, model-view-controller, eloquent, laravel-5, user-registration

I need to register a new user and store data in two tables separately, the Users table will hold classic id /name / email / password information while the User_details table will hold different information related to the new registered user, for example gender, age, user_pic etc. Now, is there a way to modify the standard authcontroller and stuff from laravel 5.1 to accomplish that task? I mean, how do you tell the controller in the create function to use two different tables? AFAIK the authcontroller now uses User model to store the data in the DB but I need to use also the User_detail model because that is where I specify the fillable columns of my User_detail table. Any clue? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Modify `AuthController`'s `create()` function. If you have added relation for your model you can easily add this it somewhat it would be like this

```
  $user =User::create($data);
  $user_details = new User_Detail();
  $user_details->fill($data); 
  //If your have added fillable in User_Detail
  return $user_details->save($user);
```

This create function is called in `RegistersUsers` trait, For more information about [inserting related models](http://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#inserting-related-models).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I kind of get it however now I have a doubt. The user_details table has a 'user_id' column that references 'id' in Users table. When the function stores data for the new users the 'id' gets automatically valued (auto increment)... so will the 'user_id' column in User_details tabled be valued accordingly? Shouldn't I get the 'id' value somehow before filling the User_details table?

Comment: No you don't need to explicitly add `id` to User_details table, If you gave relation correctly it will work. `User::create()` returns newly created object with its `id` you can use `dump()` helper function to see that. Then you are passing that to `save()` So eloquent does remaning magic.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to figure out how to modify the AuthController. I hope I can make it, I'm a newbie.

Comment: @Chriz74 if my answer working for you, Please accept my answer it would be help others to find answer. `AuthController` is there in `App\Http\Controllers\Auth` folder

Comment: so please let me know if I got your hint correctly, I wrote this code: http://pastebin.com/0BnUyYST ... so what does the last line do exactly  return $user_details->save([$user]);  ?

Comment: I can't be very sure about your code unless you give me you models and migrations. Anyway there is typo `return $user_details->save($user);` must be like this. I updated my answer check the link

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81629/discussion-between-chriz74-and-shanoop).

Comment: Hello, so I tried the code and I can confirm it works only with save([$user]); .. the point now is the subsequent login fails with Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Auth\Guard::login() must implement interface Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable, boolean given